# Using the Replace method in VBA leaves numbers stored as strings

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working with a workbook which uses a strange space as a thousands separator. The numbers including this separator are treated as text by Excel. When I remove this separator using the Find & Replace tool, the numbers get properly recognized as numbers. When I do the same using VBA, using the Cells.Replace method, the numbers keep being stored as text. A green corner then appears on the cells containing these numbers, allowing me to convert them to the number format, but this option doesn't seem to be exploitable in VBA  as this action isn't recorded by the macro recorder.

I may copy my worksheet's cells to an array, then loop through the values to replace the thousands separator, then paste the array back to the worksheet. My question is: is there a more efficient way to remove these thousands separators so that my numbers get treated as numbers?

Comment: can you upload a sample workbook with just 5 cells filled up so we can see what that strange character is? You can upload the sample file in wikisend.com and share the link here.

Comment: I assume the strange space is Chr(160) which is non-break space but whatever it is you must know to be able to replace it.  The best I can think of is a loop using Finding to set `Rng` to each cell containing a strange space.  If `Rng` is  not `Nothing`, `Rng.Value = Val(Replace(Rng.Value,StrangeSpace, " "))` to remove the strange space and force evaluation of the result.

Comment: @SiddharthRout: [link](http://wikisend.com/download/131700/sample.xlsx)

Comment: @TonyDallimore: the space is indeed a non-break space. But using the Find method in a loop turns out to be slow. Copying the worksheet's values to an array, and editing them in it is a lot faster. The only problem is that I get an "Insufficient memory" error with very large tables.

Comment: You could try loading 10,000 (or whatever) rows at a time to avoid the "insufficient memory" error.  How do you force the re-evaluate of the editted values?

Comment: What do you mean by re-evaluate? Basically, I copy the array back to the range after it has been edited.

Comment: Sorry about the re-evaluate question.  I was thinking of a different problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numbers with a non-break space as thousands separator and a coma as decimal separator were stored as text. Using the `Cells.Replace` method in VBA to remove the space didn't convert the values to number format, instead leaving them stored as text. The solution was using `Cells.Replace` a second time to replace comas with dots for VBA to treat the values as numbers and copy them to the worksheet as such. Excel then formats the numbers according to the regional settings (replacing dots back with comas if necessary).

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean the space between 9 and 5 in Cell B3 and B5? If yes, then just removing the space will not solve the problem. You need to remove the comma as well to convert it into a number and then format it using a proper thousand separator. See this code and the snapshots

**SNAPSHOT**

[image]

**CODE**

```
Sub Sample()
    With Sheets("Feuil1").Columns(2)
        .Replace What:=" ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
        xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

        .Replace What:=",", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
        xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

        .NumberFormat = "#,##0"
    End With
End Sub
```

HTH

Comment: I realize that the solution has to work with any regional settings. My system's decimal separator is the coma (,), thus, removing the space using the Find & Replace tool (without VBA) suffices for Excel to treat the value as a number. However, VBA's internal decimal separator seems to be the point (.), thus, when I use the .Replace method as you did, VBA thinks it is working with a string, and copies the edited value back to the cell as a string. That's why I get the green corner suggesting to convert the cell to the number format after using the .Replace method.

Comment: ... Since I can't use the .Replace method, the best solution seems to be copying the Range's values to an array, removing spaces and replacing comas by `Application.DecimalSeparator`, then copying the array back to the range. One problem is that this removes any leading apostrophes used to force text conversion in my table, as it isn't included in the .Value or the .Formula properties.

Comment: The other method would be to record a macro :) And then manually copy the data between 9 and 5. Then do a replace. similarly replace the decimal separator. See what the macro spits out?

Comment: I did that. As I tried to explain, the Find & Replace method works when I do it manually: the cell's contents are converted to numbers. But when I replay the recorded macro, the cell's contents remain in text format and Excel suggests to convert them to numbers using a little button that appears next to the cell. [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/lQjIC.jpg)

Comment: can you post the code that the macro spits? Also in that macro are you replacing the separators as well? I am curious how your data looks on your pc? Would it be possible for you to post a snapshot as well like I have done above?

Comment: This is the macro code: http://pastebin.com/kKGYZ1Gv
Before recording the macro: [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/OPmGk.jpg).
After recording the macro: [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/p6CeT.jpg).
After canceling the Find & Replace action and running the recorded macro: [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/a0vid.jpg).

Comment: Yes. You are missing one line in the code. What happens if you include the code to replace the ","  with "" as well? Don't include `.NumberFormat = "#,##0"` at the moment

Comment: If I include the code to remove the coma, the value gets converted to a number (without any decimal separator, obviously). But if I edit the code to replace the coma with a dot, the value gets converted to a number AND keeps its coma as a separator. This is very counter-intuitive, but it works. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Since I replace comas with dots, yes. :)

Comment: Yes for region specific you will have to do that :)

Answer (score 2):

The above answer is right.
The issue comes from Excel regional settings. (i.e. : In France numbers are formatted 1234,56 whereas it would be 1234.56 in the english version of Excel)
Using the find & replace tool, does not affect the regional settings.

However when using VBA to replace dots by comas, VBA being english based sets all the numbers as string.
If you replace separators back to dots, numbers will show up following the regional settings (dots for english settings, comas for France).

Hope this helps